# Performing an action on many multi-page pdf files on Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

I need to to perform an action on many multi-page pdf files in Photoshop. However, using the image processor in the scripts submenu performs that action on only the first pages of the pdf files. Is there an easy way to do it? Or do I have to convert all the multi-page pdf files to jpg images then perform the action on them? Thanks.

Comment: Is your PDF made of **ONLY raster images**? If not, then Photoshop is an inappropriate editor.

Comment: Yes, only raster images. What do you suggest, please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Photoshop only sees one page of a PDF at a time. There's no way to open a multi-page PDF and keep it multi-pages. Each page must be opened as a separate Photoshop document. No clue what your action entails, but there are PDF editors which support multiple pages.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I think this would probably take more than just an Action to be honest. Perhaps it could be scripted?  If you could get a script which would load each PDF page as a layer, then you could export all layers as PNG/JPG using Export > Layers to Files.  I found this [script on the Adobe Forum](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/open-pdf-pages-as-layers/td-p/10425413?page=1) which I haven't tested. Maybe you could try it.